# Failing to visualise Steiner's argument - Isoperimetric Theorem

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima

My question is regarding Steiner's (incomplete) proof for the Isoperimetric problem, as presented in the book [*What is Mathematics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/What_Is_Mathematics.html?id=UfdossHPlkgC).
 In a critical step, Steiner asks to readjust half the 'assumed' maximum area in such a way that the two end lengths become 90 degrees at the curve.

Then he argues that this has a greater area (because for two sides, the right angle produces maximum area) hence there is a contradiction—we found another similar curve with a greater area.

He proceeds to say that it must be a right angle at all points. Thus it's a circle.

I am struggling to accept the 'readjustment' argument. I just can't see it.
Two questions:

1. How can we readjust the sides without effecting the shaded area?
2. How can we readjust the sides without effecting the total length (which is a constant i.e. $L/2$)

In an [article by Viktor Blåsjö](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/blasjo526.pdf) I read that we have to assume the areas 'glued' on top of the triangle, but then wouldn't re-adjusting the areas create a kind of a kink at the point?

[image: Steiner's Isoperimetric Proof]

Comment: I have edited your question to be a bit less chatty and to include a link to the cited book.  There is still some room for improvement:  you say "At some place on the internet..."  Can you please provide links?

Comment: Hi Xander! Thanks for the swift response. Here's the link: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/blasjo526.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the shaded regions are made of cardboard and the point $O$ is a hinge. Opening/closing the hinge won't affect the area or outer perimeter of the shaded cardboard pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I understand your suggestion, but I still wonder, wouldn't that action make the region convex at O?
Do we then have to proceed like the earlier argument of making convex shapes concave (because they have a greater area per length)
Wouldn't we then have to make it concave by a reflection thereby making it in some weird shape (of greater area), but losing the point of interest i.e O?

Comment: @hargun3045 It doesn't matter if the adjusted figure has some kind of concavity.  The point is that if you start with a figure which is not a circle, you can construct a new figure with the same perimeter but which has larger area by building a triangle in it, then "opening the hinge" so that it forms a right angle.

Comment: Hey Xander. Sorry, I guess I mixed the convex & concave terms above, but thanks for understanding it and answering it. So if I understand, Steiner's just saying we can have an alternate arrangement with greater area. So he proceeds to say that the only way to resolve this contradiction is if we assume a figure that subtends 90 deg at every point? Is that it? If so I guess I over-complicated the proof.